# Workload distribution in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to make a Workload distribution in SQL but it's seems hard.

My data are :

```
work-station | workload
------------------------
Station1     |  500 
Station2     |  450 
Station3     |  50 
Station4     |  600 
Station5     |  2 
Station6     |  350
```

And :

```
Real Worker Number : 5
```

My needs are the following :

- I required the exact match between real worker number than theoretical worker number (distribution)
- I don't want to put someone in a station if it's not required (example : station5)
- I don't want to know if my workers will be able to finish the complete workload
- I want the best theoretical placement of my workers to have the best productivity

Is it possible to make this WorkLoad Distribution in a sql Request ?

Possible result :

```
work-station | workload | theoretical worker distribution
------------------------
Station1     |  500     |    1
Station2     |  450     |    1
Station3     |  50      |    0
Station4     |  600     |    2
Station5     |  2       |    0
Station6     |  350     |    1
```

Comment: Your question seems to be leaving lots and lots out.  What is a "theorical worker number (distribution)"?  How do you know what is required?  How is "best theorical placement" determined?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation : my theoretical worker number is the placement of my workers in the different station (as my possible result). Nothing is required, but more you will put a worker in a big workload station, more the productivity will be. I don't really know how is the "best theoretical placement"...

Comment: This is really vague. Can you dumb down your requirements so strangers on the interwebs can understand? Your natural choice of words to explain requirement may or may not help us understand because we are not aware of your business requirements.

Comment: You have five workers and want to distribute the workload. But why have two workers caring about the 600 and nobody for the 50? Wouldn't it be better to have one for the 600 and one for the 50? What is the rule applied here?

Comment: With 6 total stations and 5 workers, wouldn't the best distribution be 1 on each with only 1 having 0 workers? and that 1 with 0 workers being the station not required, ex: station 5 as mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simplistic way to do it by prorating the workers by the percentage of total work assigned to each station.

The complexity comes from making sure that an integer number of workers is assigned and that the total number of assigned workers equals the number of workers that are available.  Here is the query that does that:

```
with params as ( SELECT 5 total_workers FROM DUAL),
info ( station, workload) AS (
SELECT 'Station1', 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Station2', 450 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Station3', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Station4', 600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Station5', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Station6', 350 FROM DUAL ),
targets as (
select station, 
       workload,
       -- What % of total work is assigned to station?
       workload/sum(workload) over ( partition by null) pct_work,
       -- How many workers (target_workers) would we assign if we could assign fractional workers?
       total_workers * (workload/sum(workload) over ( partition by null)) target_workers,
       -- Take the integer part of target_workers
       floor(total_workers * (workload/sum(workload) over ( partition by null))) target_workers_floor,
       -- Take the fractional part of target workers
       mod(total_workers * (workload/sum(workload) over ( partition by null)),1) target_workers_frac
from params, info )
select t.station, 
       t.workload,
       -- Start with the integer part of target workers
       target_workers_floor + 
       -- Order the stations by the fractional part of target workers and assign 1 additional worker to each station until
       -- the total number of workers assigned = the number of workers we have available.
       case when row_number() over ( partition by null order by target_workers_frac desc ) 
            <= total_workers - sum(target_workers_floor) over ( partition by null) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END target_workers
from params, targets t
order by station;


+----------+----------+----------------+--+
| STATION  | WORKLOAD | TARGET_WORKERS |  |
+----------+----------+----------------+--+
| Station1 | 500      | 1              |  |
+----------+----------+----------------+--+
| Station2 | 450      | 1              |  |
+----------+----------+----------------+--+
| Station3 | 50       | 0              |  |
+----------+----------+----------------+--+
| Station4 | 600      | 2              |  |
+----------+----------+----------------+--+
| Station5 | 2        | 0              |  |
+----------+----------+----------------+--+
| Station6 | 350      | 1              |  |
+----------+----------+----------------+--+
```

Comment: Nice solution, but why don't you remove all those unneccessary `partition by null`?

Comment: Wow! awesome solution. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help on this big subject.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks.  The `partition by null` is a habit / personal preference.  I really can't defend it.  You're right: they're not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Below query should work:

First I divide workers to the stations that has more workload than mean work load.

Then I divide the rest of the workers to the stations in the same order of their remaining workloads.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55491/12

5 represent the number of workers.

```
SELECT
    workload,
    station,
    SUM (worker_count)
FROM
    (
SELECT workload, station, floor( workload / ( SELECT SUM (workload) / 5 FROM work_station ) ) worker_count -- divide workers to the stations have more workload then mean
      FROM
      work_station works
UNION ALL
    SELECT t_table.*, 1
    FROM ( SELECT workload, station
            FROM work_station
            ORDER BY
                ( workload - floor( workload / ( SELECT SUM (workload) / 5 FROM work_station ) ) * ( SELECT SUM (workload) / 5 FROM work_station )
                ) DESC
        ) t_table
    WHERE
        rownum < ( 5 - ( SELECT SUM ( floor( workload / ( SELECT SUM (workload) / 5 FROM work_station ) ) ) FROM work_station ) + 1 
        ) -- count of the rest of the workers
) table_sum
GROUP BY
    workload,
    station
ORDER BY
  station
```